# How to focus on no inputs when form loads?

Tags: html, forms

How would I ensure no inputs are focused when a form loads? At the moment by default, it seems to focus on my first input element.

```
<form>
  <input>  <-- When I load the page, this input is focused.
  <input>
  <input>
<form>
```

I'm not sure why, but two people have asked for more code and a working example? So here's the whole project!

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <form>
        First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lname">
     </form>
   </body>
 </html>
```

When the page loads the first input is focused. I would like NO inputs to be focused. I am a little confused at the confusion...

Comment: post some sample of your code please.

Comment: That enough code? lol. I don't want any inputs focused/selected when the page loads.

Comment: A working example is needed. This means a code snippet including your CSS, HTML, and any other languages that may be affecting it.

Comment: This is such a simple thing to do, that I don't know that an example is even necessary at all, however, in the future, it would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another input like this.

```
<input style="display:none;" aria-hidden="true" autofocus></input>
```

Breakdown: Make the input invisible, then make it so screenreaders will not read it, and lastly, make it draw focus.